# Wifi Hotspot discovery/Scan in Xamarin IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

All,

I am trying to list all available wifi-hotspots for my device ? Any thoughts on how to implement this in Xamarin IOS?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware apple still does not have any public APIs for you to consume in order to query a list of current Wifi networks that are available to your device.

Because of this there is no feature within Xamarin to do this either.

There is an Objective-C library that uses privates APIs for this though that you could user, although I've never tried it myself. [Follow this link to check it out.](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler)

Its worth noting that unless apples guidelines for app store submissions have changed and you were to create a binding to Stumbler to consume within a Xamarin based application, you would not be able to submit this App to the App Store as Apple will reject it because it will use private APIs.